# Can a fair coin have dependent tosses?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am studying a bit of probability theory now and I want to know if a fair coin can have dependent tosses. I mean a coin has $50%$ chance each of getting heads or tails. Does it make sense to say the result of $n$'th coin toss has $70%$ chance of being the same as the result of $n-1$ 'th toss? Or when one says result of coin toss is dependent on previous results, can that coin be fair? Does it make sense to say something like that?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by fair. I think a good definition of fair is that tosses are uniform and iid, and this rules out dependence. Why do you think there is a good definition of fairness that allows for non-independence?

Comment: In the dependent toss scenario I mentioned in the question, the result is more likely to be same as previous toss. This scenario treats heads and tails fairly. In the sense the result of previous toss being heads or tails, has same effect on the next toss result.

Comment: I mean if a coin or any event has memory of previous events, the usual way of saying "the probability of getting heads for the coin is 0.7" it doesn't and shouldn't make sense right?

Comment: Well, it also must mean that some sequences of tosses are more likely than others, which doesn't sound fair to me. In any case -- right now this question boils down to what the meaning of the word is with little mathematical motivation for why we should be interested in that discussion, so I'm not sure it's a good question for this site. But I could be wrong. Let's see if this question generates any interesting answers.

Comment: As pointed out, coin fairness is defined so that it implies independence of random variables.  If you only require that heads and tails be equiprobable, things change.  For $i \in \{0,1\}$, if the probability of $i$ after $i$ is $p$, then the ratio of the numbers of ones and zeros tends to $1$ in the long run, for every $p\in(0,1)$. Another interesting example is Polya's urn, when the numbers of red and black balls start equal.  The initial expectation of the fraction of red balls after $n$ turns is $1/2$, but the probability of drawing a red ball depends on how many red balls have been drawn.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a fair coin is when a sequence of independent Bernoulli trials has an equal probability 1/2 for either outcome per trial. Saying that the *n*th coin toss has a 70% chance of being the same as the *n*-1th, or is dependent on the *n*-1th toss contradicts the definition of a fair coin because each trial must be independent, and the probability of either outcome must be 1/2 for each toss. If you had a coin that did take previous tosses into account, this would be a biased coin. Thus, stating "a fair coin where each toss is dependent on previous results" is illogical.

Comment: Yep... what Grant wrote...

Comment: Thanks a lot. just one more thing.Doesn't biased mean unequal probability?

Comment: That is correct. Biased means there is an unequal probability. This would be the case if a coin toss took previous tosses into account.

Comment: @jnyan "Biaised coin" is often used to talk about a coin which has a fixed probability p of yielding heads, such that tosses are independent and identically distributed, and "biaised" only means "p can differ from 1/2". If you have a more complex magical coin that somehow remembers its previous tosses, you should probably invent your own vocabulary for it and define it explicitly. Another common word is "[loaded](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/loaded)".

Comment: Note that if p ≈ 0.184 or 0.816 and the tosses are i.i.d., then the probability that two tosses are equal is 70%. This is found by solving the equation p² + (1-p)² = 0.70.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what exactly you mean by the word "fair."

In its common usage, the word connotes that the tosses are independent and that each throw has an even chance of heads or tails. So if you mean the word in any way close to how it is universally understood, then no, the word "fair" cannot include the scenarios you described.

But that answer's no fun, of course. So let's run a thought experiment: if you were to distill it down to something axiomatic, what are the most sensible conditions to impose on the word "fair" (assuming that you don't want the default idea)? To me, "fairness" demands that heads and tails should on some level be equally common. I'd argue that having the same unconditional probability on a given throw being heads or tails is the more important property to keep. So perhaps your coin could just be the same throw, repeated infinitely often, after a first random throw. Perhaps you impose some strong inter-throw correlation like you described. Maybe each throw alternated with probability 1. But at the end of the day, calling any of these "fair" is quite a stretch and you'd be hard-pressed to find a neutral observer who would support those labels.